# how to make a popup window centered

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a jsp page which calling a function getModify() in utility.js file. that function performing some action and redirecting some values to next jsp page using window.open()..
am getting the another jsp page as popup window.. how to get the popup window center of the screen.

my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="script/Utility.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="SearchMenu21" onclick="getModify();" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="SearchMenu21" name="search5.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/search.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Modify
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my utility.js file:

```
function getModify(){
    var whereCondn = "";
    //alert(gbshowgridFlag);
    if(dijit.byId('dynamicgridCWPROCESS')){
        var selctedItem = dijit.byId('dynamicgridCWPROCESS').selection.getSelected();
        if(selctedItem.length){
            dojo.forEach(selctedItem, function(selectedItem){
                if(selectedItem !== null){
                    dojo.forEach(dijit.byId('dynamicgridCWPROCESS').store.getAttributes(selectedItem), function(attribute){
                        var value = dijit.byId('dynamicgridCWPROCESS').store.getValues(selectedItem, attribute);
                        //alert(value);
                        if(attribute == "PROCESS_ID"){
                            whereCondn = whereCondn+attribute+"="+value;
                        }
                        //alert("new alert"+whereCondn);
                        window.open("modifyTask.jsp?MODIFY="+response,'title','height=600px,width=800px,scrollbars=no,sizable=yes,toolbar=no,statusbar=no');
                    });
                }
            });
            //alert("grid row selected");
        }else{
            alert("grid row not selected");
        }
    }
    if(gbshowgridFlag==false){
        alert("grid not loaded");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass "top" and "left" properties for the popup.

window.open("modifyTask.jsp?MODIFY="+response,'title','height=600px,width=800px,scrollbars=no,sizable=yes,toolbar=no,statusbar=no,top='+ topVar + ',left='+leftVar);

Use calculations based on screen.height , and your optimal popup size to decide topVar and leftVar

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
var x = screen.width / 2 - 800 / 2;
var y = screen.height / 2 - 600 / 2;
window.open("modifyTask.jsp?MODIFY="+response,'title' ,'height=600px,width=800px,scrollbars=no,sizable=yes,toolbar=no,statusbar=no,left=' + x + ',top=' + y);
```